# Unable to use "ctrl + c" to close a port used for visualization opened through python MESA on Mac OS

Tags: python, mesa-abm

[This is the code I am using to run a visualization using python MESA. However, as per the tutorial, I should be able to stop the vizualization window using "ctrl + c" in the terminal but that dosen't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U664D.png)

[This is a snip of the vizualization opened on safari.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXlgv.png)

Link to the tutorial: https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/adv_tutorial.html

[This image shows the instructions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4aqU.png)

I have tried the following:
lsof -i : 8521
kill -9 PID #

But this dosen't work.

I also tried "ctrl + ." and it restarts the kernal but dosen't close the port and the vizualization.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please try not to upload images of code / errors, read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

"ctrl + ." restarts the kernel but doesn't close the visualization.
I tried to close the visualization manually and run the code again and it worked!